# Screen capture via WinAPI (security)

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to determine that now my screen (or window of my C++ program) is being captured by any of the running programs on the PC?

Comment: What if I use my phone and take a photo of the screen?

Comment: :) I thought about winapi, does it leave logs of calls to certain functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It seems there is no way to detect a screen capture until now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163909/is-there-any-way-to-detect-a-screen-capture-or-recording) But you can use [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity)  to protect the window content from being captured or copied only when the Desktop Window Manager(DWM) is composing the desktop.

Comment: It should be noted that in the interests of security, any _malicious_ tool such as RAT software can typically bypass or hijack and mimic the graphics driver and/or hook the OS kernel.  If it does this properly, you will be unable to detect that anything is watching and even the OS will be oblivious to it.